# Get queryset by using filter objects on template in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    hot_league = models.ManyToManyField(HotLeague, blank=True)

class HotLeague(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    price_pool = models.IntegerField()
    winner = models.IntegerField()
```

In Views:

```
match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk)
```

Here i need to access this `Match` queryset.

that's why

In template:

```
{% for hot_league in match.hot_league.all %}
```

By writing `match.hot_league.all` in template I can get all queryset of `HotLeague` class. But I want to use `filter` here with user. Like in `views` we can use `HotLeague.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. But `{% for hot_league in match.hot_league.filter(user=request.user) %}` is not working on template.

How can I do that kind of filter in `template`?

Comment: can you share the code of your `HotLeague` model?

Comment: Please do *not* filter in the template. You should filter in the view. Can you share the details of your view?

Comment: @NalinDobhal I edit my question. See please..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem need this filter in template. See my edit post please..

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do that kind of filter in template?

Templates are *deliberately* restricted to avoid that. Some template processors, like [*Jinja*](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) can make function calls, but usually if you have to do that, something is wrong with the design. Views should determine *what* to render, and templates should render that content in a nice format.

In your view, you thus can render this as:

```
def some_view(request, pk):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk)
    hot_leagues = match.hot_league.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(
        request,
        'some_template.html',
        {'match': match, 'hot_leagues': hot_leagues}
    )
```

In your template, you can then render this like:

```
{% for hot_league in hot_leagues %}
    <!-- -->
{% endfor %}
```